# Changing the display of fragments from a fragment pager adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am using a pre created example from Android studio. It is found by going to a new project, selecting blank project with a actionbar tab navigation style with swiping.

It obviously work and it changes an editText's text to represent a the number of the tab that you are currently viewing.

What is confusing is I can't find how I can specify different layouts for each fragment. Ultimately I want to have a completely different looking screen for each of my 3 tabs. I thought I would create three separate fragments with each having it's own layout but it seems here that this is sort of done on the fly by the example.

Has anyone played with this example and can let me know how to customise each of the fragments with the XML viewer/designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the changes you need to do in example or can create a new project as well.

**1.Write your all views as Fragments instead of Activities which you want to show in your navigation tabs like**

```
Fragment1, Fragment2,...
```

Fragment will be the super class for all your Fragments.

Create xml layouts for each of your fragment and override the onCreateView method of your Fragment classes like :

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     // Get the view from respectivelayout.xml

     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.respectivelayoput, container, false);

    // Do whatever you want to do like an activity here for all the tabs

    return rootView;
  }
```

**2.Create an new class which overrides FragmentPagerAdapter for swiping between tabs, something like this**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // Declare the number of ViewPager pages
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            // Open FragmentTab1.java
            case 0:
                FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1(context);
                return fragmenttab1;
            // Open FragmentTab2.java
            case 1:
                FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2(context);
                return fragmenttab2;
           //And so on.., make sure cases must be equal to page count you specified
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

**3.Now create a xml layout for your activity only holding a viewpager inside it like (I am using support v4 library for fragment)**

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**4.Now here the code snippet of your MainActivity.java(Same in exapmle nothing changed)**

```
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        yourAdaperInstance= new YourFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  //created in xml

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < yourAdaperInstance.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }

        // getCount and getPageTitle are defined in your FragmentPagerAdapter, This is the best practice or else you can add tabs and define names everything in Activity also
    }
```

You need to Set the TabListener as well but it comes with the example nothing needs to be changed in that.

**All these classes(MainActivity, YourFragmentPagerAdapter, Fragment1,Fragment2.. ) are in same Activity class for Studio example but you can make them all separate, I prefer that.**